# How can I get a main photo profile using VK Sdk?

Tags: android, vk, vk-sdk

I can't find appropriate methods because all I have found are deprecated now.
I tried this one
`VKRequest yourRequest = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"photo_50"))`
but it doesn't work, there is no class VKApi in VK Sdk now

I want to log in Vk and if it went successfully I want to show a person's avatar on the screen